jsPdf when working in medium screen like(laptop) works fine but downloaded pdf from monitor screens not coming aligned properly
This is the below code where I am using html2canvas to convert html to pdf . Here pdf download in medium screens downloading as per expected but when same is rendered from large screens. In pdf few page coming blank content and getting shuffled order. How do I fix this issue for all screens set same.
Here is my code to pdf download.
setTimeout(()=>{
        var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm','letter',true);
        const htmlInput:any=document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv')
        for(let i=0; i<htmlInput.length;i++)
        {
          html2canvas(htmlInput[i], {  
            // scale: 2,    
            onclone: function (clonedDoc) {
              clonedDoc.getElementById("selfAssessment").style.display = "block";
            },
           
          }).then(async (canvas) => {
            var imgWidth = 219;
            var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
            doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 30, 10, imgWidth, imgHeight);
            if(i+1==htmlInput.length)
            {
              doc.save('data.pdf');
            }
           else
            {
              doc.addPage()
            }
   
          });
        }     
     
    },2000)


If you ask me give up on fronted generated PDFs especially if you have multiple screen options. Go server side.

We are running a for loop and loading asynchronous call, but we should note that, they complete at any arbitary time, this is causing the problem I believe, the solution for this can be use async and await to wait for one sequence to complete before executing another.
  sequence = async () => {
    var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm','letter',true);
    const htmlInput:any=document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv')
    for(let i=0; i<htmlInput.length;i++) {
      const canvas = await html2canvas(htmlInput[i], {  
        // scale: 2,    
        onclone: function (clonedDoc) {
          clonedDoc.getElementById("selfAssessment").style.display = "block";
        },
      });
      var imgWidth = 219;
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 30, 10, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      if(i+1==htmlInput.length)
      {
        doc.save('data.pdf');
      }
     else
      {
        doc.addPage()
      }
    }
  }

